# Multiple hard drives : Booting Ubuntu + Other Os / or Other Ubuntu version / or Duplicate Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have a very simple question, and because of my limited knowledge UEFI i can´t figure it out.

**I have a laptop that in the bios it does not provide a legacy boot option. The only option is UEFI**

**The number of nvme slots on the laptop is : 2 nvme slots.
and we are going to start with both slots empty on the laptop**

1. I insert 1 clean nvme stick on the laptop, and I insert Ubuntu 22.04 LTS live usb flash drive, Ubuntu is installed with UEFI
2. then i  remove the nvme stick from the laptop.

Then i repeat the process:

1. I insert another clean nvme stick on the laptop, and i insert  windows install boot usb. Windows is installed, on another nvme using UEFI.
2. then i  remove the nvme stick from the laptop.

**SO.....**

A) You have 1 nvme that is not inserted in the laptop. (wich contains Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)
2) You have another nvme that is not inserted in the laptop (wich has or windows).

Since the laptop has 2 nvme slots, i want to know the following:

what happens if after all this process, you insert both NVMe sticks into the laptop? would i be able to choose during boot/ or bios, the win10 or Ubuntu 22.04 LTS ? or it will fail and it will require some sort of boot menu installation?

Comment: "what happens if you insert both NVMe into the laptop?" I'd say try it out. Only 1/2 of this is on topic: the Ubuntu part. What happens with Windows is outside of your scrope :) "or it will fail and it will require some sort of boot menu installation?" There are more options: one of them is that you have to pick one from bios to boot from it. Why is there a need to remove the disks?

Comment: thanks, i have updated the info on the original question since it was not very clear. im using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.  And i just wondered how uefi would suppose to work without actually opening the laptop

Comment: UEFI normally "forgets" UEFI entry when a drive is removed. But most seem to auto find a new Windows entry. Grub would have to be updated `sudo update-grub` to add Windows to grub menu. If Ubuntu entry missing, you may be able to boot fallback or drive entry which is like the entry for an external device. Or use efibootmgr from live installer to add new UEFI entry. Or totally reinstall grub which uses efibootmgr to add entry and install/reinstall rest of grub.